# Regex: Removes all HTML Tags and returns just the text?

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to strip just text values from below html with js.

```
var Str = "<span style="">MY name is KERBEROS.</span><B>HELLO Everbody</B>"
```

All text strips with codes that is below;

```
[^<>]+(?=[<])
```

But i want to strip just UPPERCASE words. Clresult must be: MY, KERBEROS, HELLO
Thank you already now for your suggestions.

Regards,
Kerberos

Comment: In jQuery, `$(Str).text()` does that. (I mean removing the tags)

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Do you want to strip HTML tags or uppercase words or what?

Comment: Sounds like he wants to strip out the HTML tags, *then* extract just the uppercase words.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code, gives output: MY,KERBEROS,HELLO

```
<script>
String.prototype.stripHTML = function()
{
        var matchTag = /<(?:.|\s)*?>/g;
        return this.replace(matchTag, "");
};

String.prototype.getUpperCaseWords = function()
{
        var matchTag1 = /\b([A-Z])+\b/g;
        var o = this.match(matchTag1);
        return o;
};


var Str = "<span style=''>MY name is KERBEROS.</span><B>HELLO Everbody</B>";

var out1 = Str.stripHTML();
var out2 = out1.getUpperCaseWords();

alert(out2);

</script>
```

This is another solution in JavaScript using just one line of regex:

```
String.prototype.stripHTML = function()
{
        var matchTag = /<(?:.|\s)*?>/g;
        return this.replace(matchTag, "").match(/\b([A-Z])+\b/g);
};


var Str = "<span style=''>MY name is SATYA PRAKASH.</span><B>HELLO Everyone</B>";

var out1 = Str.stripHTML();
```

Comment: This much from a regex can be removed: ([a-zA-Z]){1,1}

Comment: and your example string is wrongly using double quote here <span style="">... It should be <span style=''>

Comment: I'm not understanding why you wrote the `matchTag` regex like that... `(?:` is a non-capturing group, right? Then you match anything OR a space? `.` already includes space... and why bother with the non-capturing group? Why not simply `/<.*?>/g`.. and in your second one, `/\b[A-Z]+\b/g` The ()s are unneeded.

Comment: Also, the inconsistency..you explicitly name your first regex (matchTag) but then use the second one inline...

Comment: I am not getting you fully. And that HTML stripping tag is working and given by kerberos. I have not worked on validity of that. Finally every thing is working and giving output as intended.  (if you asked for 2nd code block than that was just for another one function solution. 1st block code is good and flexible. and for 2nd block of code, asker can also do that much work).

Comment: @Ralph, " in your second one, /\b[A-Z]+\b/g The ()s are unneeded." This is true. I was working by using replace. so that time case was different. I was considering "Everyone". 1st is capital. I am going to change that.

Comment: Was referring to the second example. Not saying it's wrong.. just saying it could be made cleaner :)

Comment: ok. Kerberos will take care of that. but I should have earned few points by this time! shocking. :)

Comment: Thank you very much Satya Prakash. I'm sorry for late answer. I could'n try your suggestion yet. But when i'll try, notice you result.

Comment: Until you try and close the question, Ralph will continue fighting with me. ;)

Comment: Give up. Question is mine and i'm happy for your help. Thank you again.

Comment: Hi again. Acctually i asked question wrong. Exactly i want to get result like this "<span style=''>My name is Kerberos.</span><B>Hello Everbody</B>" I mean i want to change uppercase words to first letter up from full html source. But html tags must be exclude in this transfrom process.

Comment: htmlSoursce= htmlSoursce.replace(
     /([A-ZÖİŞÜĞÇ])([A-ZÖİŞÜĞÇ]+)/g,
     function(a,m1,m2) {
      if (a.indexOf("FILE")== -1){
     return m1 + IReplace(m2);
      }
      else{
     return a;   
    }
     } // i use this code for transform.